# EditText Floating Labels Gravity

Tags: android, label, gravity, floating

I need to change the label position from left to right,
any ideas?

http://arjunu.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Floating-label.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to put the field in Arabic, then the whole field is shifted to the right

android:hint="\u200F TEXT"

Comment: What do you mean by put the field in Arabic? I'm facing the same issue and I've already put the layout in layout-ar but it still doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean to put field in ar?

Comment: (android:hint="\u200F Texto" ) this is the solution

Answer (score 0):

set the EditText gravity to Right and make sure it's width is "match_parent", the label and the hint would stick to right side

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextUserMail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"             
            android:gravity="right"
            android:hint="mail"
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: The solution was to put the field in Arabic, then the whole field is shifted to the right